# Google Glass - Share Images

Tags: php, html, google-glass

I'm developing a "sharing" app for Google Glass using the Mirror API.

Basically, I want there to be another share option on the images and videos. Instead of just the default "Share to Google Plus," there will also be "Share to (Server)," which will ping a file (upload.php) on the server to upload the image/video.

From the documentation I can tell I need to use [contacts](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/contacts) to "subscribe" to the share events.

Could someone point me to a doc that explains how this can be done? I know it is possible because apps like YouTube and Facebook already achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in various languages, including php:
https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/contacts/insert#examples

You may also want to play around with the Quickstart demo app (which can also be downloaded on GitHub):
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/php

The Quickstart is a working demo that showcases the Contacts, Subscribe, and Timeline capabilities of the Mirror API.